# LPARAM as pointer to VBA variable

Tags: c, vba

I'm building a very simple win32 console application which is coded in C and compiled using Visual Studio 2010/2013.  It will have a message queue running in a separate thread from the main one. The console will be launched from VBA and then sent user defined messages via the API function `PostThreadMessage`.

I found a way to obtain all of the thread id's for the console based on it's process id.  However, I've not yet found a way to identify the correct one.  What I'm doing presently is sending a message to all of the console threads.  In that message I'm passing a pointer to one of my VBA variables as the LPARAM argument via the `VarPtr` function.

The thread is receiving the message but the app is crashing when it tries to write the id to the VBA variable.  I know it's possible to pass a VBA variable pointer to a DLL function.  I've used that approach in the past with API function `EnumWindows`.  However, I'm completely new to C programming and cannot figure out how to do the same thing in my console code.

Below are the steps I've taken to troubleshoot this issue:

- Created a new empty Visual C++ Win32 Console Application project
- Added a new item to Source Files folder named Shell.c
- Added the following code to Shell.c

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <Windows.h>
  #define WM_GET_ID WM_USER + 1
  DWORD WINAPI MessageQueue(LPVOID n) {
      MSG msg;
      int *pVar;
      BOOL MsgReturn;
      DWORD dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
      while (1) {
          MsgReturn = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_GET_ID, WM_GET_ID);
          if (MsgReturn) {
              switch (msg.message) {
              case WM_GET_ID:
                  pVar = (int*)msg.lParam;
                  // Access violation writing location 0x0026F470
                  *pVar = (int)dwThreadId;
              }
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }
  int main() {
      CreateThread(NULL, 0, MessageQueue, NULL, 0, NULL);
      // Pause the console window to keep thread running
      getchar();
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Compiled the code as ConsoleTest.exe
- Opened a blank Excel 2013 Workbook and saved it as Pointer Testing.xlsm
- Added a new module named PointerTest
- Added the following code to the PointerTest module

  ```
  Option Explicit
  Private Type THREADENTRY32
      dwSize As Long
      cntUsage As Long
      th32ThreadID As Long
      th32OwnerProcessID As Long
      tpBasePri As Long
      tpDeltaPri As Long
      dwFlags As Long
  End Type
  Private Const WM_USER As Long = &H400
  Private Const WM_GET_ID As Long = WM_USER + 1
  Private Const WM_TERMINATE As Long = WM_USER + 2
  Private Const TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS As Long = &H2
  Private Const TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD As Long = &H4
  Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal th32ProcessID As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function PostThreadMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostThreadMessageA" (ByVal idThread As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Boolean
  Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
  Private Declare Function Thread32First Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, ByRef lpte As THREADENTRY32) As Boolean
  Private Declare Function Thread32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, ByRef lpte As THREADENTRY32) As Boolean
  Private Sub SendConsoleMsg()
      Dim PID         As Long
      Dim tHandle     As Long
      Dim dwThreadId  As Long
      Dim PName       As String
      Dim Success     As Boolean
      Dim tEntry      As THREADENTRY32
      PName = "C:\My Stuff\Visual Studio" & _
      "\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe"
      PID = Shell(PName, vbNormalFocus)
      Sleep 250
      tHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0&)
      If tHandle = -1 Then
          Debug.Print "Could not obtain thread handle"
          Exit Sub
      End If
      tEntry.dwSize = Len(tEntry)
      Success = Thread32First(tHandle, tEntry)
      If Success Then
          Do
              If tEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = PID Then
                  PostThreadMessage tEntry.th32ThreadID, _
                  WM_GET_ID, 0, VarPtr(dwThreadId)
              End If
          Loop While Thread32Next(tHandle, tEntry)
      End If
      CloseHandle tHandle
      Sleep 10
      Debug.Print dwThreadId
  End Sub
  ```

When I run the `SendConsoleMsg` procedure in VBA, the console loads and then crashes within a few seconds.  I see the access violation commented in my C code example when I go into debug mode.  Please let me know what I need to do to get this working properly.  I've searched for a solution for days and still came up dry.

## Update

I was able to get it working using the [code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Frankie_C linked for option 1.  However, I ended up changing up the DLL function calling convention from `__declspec(dllexport)` to `__stdcall` and included a DEF file for the function exports.  Also, I added another function to the DLL so I could return the thread id in VBA as a DWORD -

```
DWORD __stdcall GetConsoleThreadId() {
    WCHAR Buf[5];
    GetSharedMem(Buf, 5);
    SetSharedMem(TEXT("0"));
    return (DWORD)wcstod(Buf, '\0');
}
```

In my `MessageQueue` function, I added the following code to load the thread id into shared memory -

```
WCHAR Buf[5];
HMODULE hDLL;
FARPROC SetSharedMem;
hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\My Stuff\\Visual Studio\\SharedMem\\Debug\\SharedMem.dll"));
if (hDLL != NULL) {
    SetSharedMem = GetProcAddress(hDLL, "SetSharedMem");
    if (SetSharedMem) {
        swprintf_s(Buf, 5, L"%d", GetCurrentThreadId());
        SetSharedMem(Buf);
    }
    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that both VBA and the console have their own address spaces, so you can't pass the address of a variable from one thread and then access it in another thread; the other thread will attempt to read/write its own memory. You might try `GlobalAllock`. In stead of posting the message, you could send the message, which waits until returned from, and have the receiver return a meaningful value.

Comment: You could convert your console app into a basic Windows DLL and load it with `LoadLibrary()` so it gets loaded within the same address space as your VBA app. You'll need to use the `__stdcall` calling convention, IIRC. Or, you can create an ActiveX DLL.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you for the clarification about address space.  I was unaware of that restriction as I've never had a need to do anything outside of VBA until now.  It's possible `GlobalAlloc` may do the trick but I'll have to research it further.

@Bond Thank you for the suggestions.  However, the project I'm working on will require an active console.

Comment: If you want to use messages, why not [create a hidden window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/23/9248851.aspx) with a proper message loop on that separate thread in the console, and use `SendMessage` where the OS will handle marshaling data both ways? Even if you manage to get `PostThreadMessage` to work, local variables changed at random by an external process might surprise VBA more than you would like.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm going to attempt what Frankie_C recommended below first but I'll certainly keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all different processes have different memory spaces isolated between each other. This is one of the main characteristics of nowaday OS's: process private memory.

If you want to access shared memory from code running in 2, or more, different process you can't use GlobalAlloc(). This function come from old distinctions between local and global process memory in 16bits windows OS. So withstanding its name global doesn't mean accessible from different processes.

To make the trick you have basicacally 2 methods:

1. Use a memory mapped file ([CreateFileMapping()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx))
2. Create a shared section in a DLL loaded in more processes

In the first case you simply create a memory mapped file in the first process, then open the file in a second process then manipulate shared memory. See [this sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx), or [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686958(v=vs.85).aspx). The last put the mapped file and service routines in a DLL shared between all processes that needs access to common data.

For the second case you have to create a DLL, inside the DLL you will create a shared section using the [`SECTION` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h82ftb38.aspx) in the  `.def` file of the DLL. You can also use the `#pragma section` to associate the shared attribute.
All the data created inside the shared section is visible among any process that loads the dll.

```
//Use pragma to create a section named 'MySharedSection', readable, writable and shared
#pragma section( "MySharedSection", read, write, shared)
//Allocate the section, all data after this spec will be allocated in the new section
__declspec(allocate("MySharedSection")) 
__declspec(dllexport) char CommonBuffer[1024];
```

In the sample above I created a shared buffer of 1024 bytes that will be available to all processes that will load the DLL. The symbol is also exported making it accessible from the code that links the DLL.

This system is outdated, it was used from Win3.1 times. Today the preferred method is to use [CreateFileMapping()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for all of the info. I had an unexpected change of plans so I won't be able to test this until tomorrow.

Comment: I tried to implement the first option via the `CreateFileMapping` function referenced in the [code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you linked.  However, I received an access denied error when attempting to create the file mapping object in the global namespace.  I've never worked with DLL files before so the second option is going to take me a fair bit longer to test.

Comment: `CreateFileMapping()` has been created for exactly what you want, it seems really strange that it doesn't work for you. Have you prefixed the mapping name with "Global"? This is required to make mapping available between different processes. I.e. if you want create a mapping named "MyMapping", and made it global the name must be "Global\\MyMapping". Please read carefully the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx), and try the provided sample first to integrate it in your code.

Comment: I did use the "Global\\" prefix in VBA and my C code.  In each case, I received error 5 using API function `GetLastError`.  I checked that error number using API function `FormatMessage` and received "Access is denied." as the error description.  However, I was able to successfully implement option 1 using the DLL approach so I gave you credit for answering the question.

Comment: @ChrisD Thanks for the credit. It's not clear to me because it doesn't work. Maybe a memory problem with VBA, I'll check when I'll spare some time.